# Is there any efficient way to increment the corresponding set positions of an integer in an integer array?

Tags: python, python-2.7, bit-manipulation

Any solution consuming less than O(Bit Length) time is welcome. I need to process around 100 million large integers.

```
answer = [0 for i in xrange(100)]
def pluginBits(val):
    global answer
    for j in xrange(len(answer)):
        if val <= 0:
            break
        answer[j] += (val & 1)
        val >>= 1
```

Comment: First, why would `val` ever become negative? Second, after `log2(val)` iterations (very soon!) `val` becomes 0, and the loop breaks. Does your code make sense?

Comment: 100 million large integers in an arbitrary order? No, you can’t do something with every bit without reading every bit, which already takes linear time on the total number of bits. You should probably look for other optimizations (how large is “large”? Cython?) if there are no input constraints possible.

Comment: In case 'val' is less than 0, I don't need to increment any array position. Secondly, the iteration occurs exactly 'Bit Length' times. If the 'if' statement is removed, the loop iterates exactly 100 times all the time which is quite expensive for me considering the number of such integers.

Comment: FWIW, `answer = [0] * 100` is faster than your list comp. Also, using a global is slower than using a local. You could probably do this much faster with Numpy. Or perhaps the 3rd-party `bitarray` or `bitstring` modules could be useful (I've never used either of them).

Answer (score 0):

A speedier way to do this would be to use `'{:b}'.format(someval)` to convert from integer to a string of `'1'`s and `'0'`s. Python still needs to do similar work to perform this conversion, but doing it at the C layer in the interpreter internals involves significantly less overhead for larger values.

For conversion to actual `list` of integer 1s and 0s, you could do something like:

```
# Done once at top level to make translation table:
import string
bitstr_to_intval = string.maketrans(b'01', b'\x00\x01')

# Done for each value to convert:
bits = bytearray('{:b}'.format(origint).translate(bitstr_to_intval))
```

Since `bytearray` is a mutable sequence of values in `range(256)` that iterates the actual `int` values, you don't need to convert to `list`; it should be usable in 99% of the places the `list` would be used, using less memory and running faster.

This does generate the values in the reverse of the order your code produces (that is, `bits[-1]` here is the same as your `answer[0]`, `bits[-2]` is your `answer[1]`, etc.), and it's unpadded, but since you're summing bits, the padding isn't needed, and reversing the result is a trivial reversing slice (add `[::-1]` to the end). Summing the bits from each input can be made *much* faster by making `answer` a `numpy` array (that allows a bulk element-wise addition at the C layer), and putting it all together gets:

```
import string

bitstr_to_intval = string.maketrans(b'01', b'\x00\x01')
answer = numpy.zeros(100, numpy.uint64)

def pluginBits(val):
    bits = bytearray('{:b}'.format(val).translate(bitstr_to_intval))[::-1]
    answer[:len(bits)] += bits
```

In local tests, this definition of `pluginBits` takes a little under one-seventh the time to sum the bits at each position for 10,000 random input integers of 100 bits each, and gets the same results.